# Can my laptop whose dead GPU was fixed using a method similar to "Bake in the Oven" technique used normally afterwards..?

Tags: hardware-failure, gpu

My laptop's motherboard has an Integrated graphic card that died. The manufacturer told the the only way to fix it is by replacing the motherboard, which would have cost me a lot of money.

A local technician fixed it by heating it, and it is back from the dead, but the advice he gave me afterwards is:

"Don't use it for more than an hour"

"Don't Play Games"

The sum of all which sounded like "Don't use your laptop here after"

Is that true?
Can i use it as I normally used to or should I buy a new Motherboard?

Answer (score 1):

The Technician's advice was partly to cover himself and the shop he worked for.  He doesn't want you coming back after a week saying that the repair did nothing, and demanding your money back.

**Should** you have replaced the motherboard? Yes.  Most likely, you should have replaced the motherboard with a different integrated video chipset from the one that came with it originally.  The HP DV2000/6000/9000 series fiasco comes to mind.  If you originally had one with an NVidia chipset, and it failed, although it was possible to replace the motherboard with another of the same... you were better off replacing it with one that had an Intel chipset.  With the NVidia chipset boards, you never knew if you were getting a pre-failure board, or a repaired board that might fail again, or one that had been repaired by replacing the parts with ones that weren't defective, or one that was manufactured with non-defective chips.

Point being... the reason why your board needed to be reballed wasn't addressed necessarily with the fix.  It was repaired in a manner that saved you money because you chose cheap over best.  Did you get a working laptop back?  Yes.  Did you have to spend as much money as it would have cost to replace the motherboard?  No.  Do you actually have a reason to complain?  No.

If you wanted it fixed right, to where you could use it in any manner you would have liked, you should have replaced the motherboard.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I am currently unemployed and dont wanna bother my parents for 10x more money.. and i need my machine more than ever for job hunting.. And my machine is a Dell with AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5450

Comment: @ArunKumar Put another way, the laptop has had a hackish fix applied.  It's like fixing a tear in your shirt with duct tape - it works most of the time, but it's not as good a fix as if you had sewed the tear close.  The real question is how likely is the duct tape (or in your case the solder reflow) likely to keep working . . . as Bon Gart mentions, the tech doesn't know, and is protecting himself, but also pointing out a low confidence in the fix . . . maybe it's just scotch tape and not duct tape :P

Comment: It may indeed be that the tech doesn't have much confidence in the fix... or it could be that he repaired it in a way that *should* allow it to work, but you just have to handle it with kid gloves.  Like... for example, if instead of removing the GPU and reballing the board, he applied a heatshield to the area around it and used a heat gun on the opposite side of the board (in effect, almost reballing it)... it *should* fix it, but it isn't a proper repair.